# Making Google Sheets return integer

Tags: c#, json, google-sheets, google-oauth, google-sheets-api

I've tried messing around with Google API. I've done some things right like getting values and writing etc, but my problem is that it returns as an object, and I want to do math with the number. I've tried almost everything but nothing seems to work.

Try yourself and here's the startup guide https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/dotnet.

Here's my code:

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4;
using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace SheetsQuickstart
{
    class Program
    {
        // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
        // at ~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-dotnet-quickstart.json
        static string[] Scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.SpreadsheetsReadonly };
        static string ApplicationName = "Google Sheets API .NET Quickstart";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UserCredential credential;
            var money = 1000;
            using (var stream =
                new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                    System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-dotnet-quickstart.json");

                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            }

            // Create Google Sheets API service.
            var service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });

            // Define request parameters.
            String spreadsheetId = "1li2ibH7wtBzVmRV4CkThdT1cXAJWfOQAuxoiTTLhOBU";
            String range = "G1";
            SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.GetRequest request =
                    service.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(spreadsheetId, range);

            // Prints the names and majors of students in a sample spreadsheet:
            // https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit
            ValueRange response = request.Execute();
            var values = response.Values;
            if (values != null && values.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var row in values)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(row[0]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No data found.");
            }
            Console.Read();



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. Is the value not being returned correctly, or is it just that you're missing a cast? You've shown the sample code, but not what it does compared with what you want it to do.

Comment: So are you saying there are numeric values in the rows (actually it looks like it's a 1x1 matrix of values), but they (all 1 of them) are boxed, and you want to cast them to doubles or something?

Comment: If `row[0]` is not null where you pass it to Console.WriteLine(), what does this show you: `Console.WriteLine(row[0].GetType());`

Comment: Convert.ToInt32(row[0]) perhaps, assuming row[0] is the number you want.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm sorry. I have some numbers in a spreadsheet I want to use in my code, but when I try to do math expressions (like adding) it says 'operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'object'' because when I get the number(s) I get a list of objects and I've tried lots of ways to convert and stuff but it doesnt work for me.

Comment: You need to edit your question to give a *lot* more information about "I've tried lots of ways to convert and stuff but it doesnt work for me."

Comment: @JonSkeet yes but I can't really keep track of what I've tried so I thought it would be easier if you could try yourself even though it could take longer

Comment: No, I'm afraid you should go back and try things yourself. Stack Overflow relies on users doing research themselves first - there's no point in lots of other people trying things you've already tried. I'd start with casting - or using `GetType()` to see the actual type you *should* cast to. This time when you try things, keep a record of what you've tried.